# Sortable Materialize.css chips

Tags: jquery, materialize

Has anyone successfully implemented jQuery's `sortable` with Materialize.css chips?  I'm trying to re-order them, but the internal data does not respond to the order after sorting.

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

http://materializecss.com/chips.html

```

```
$(".location-chips").sortable({
    stop: function(e, ui){
      // This is still in the original order
      console.log($(this).material_chip('data').map(function(o){return o.tag}).join(";"))
    }
  })
```

```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with:

```
  var source, dest;
  $(".location-chips").sortable({
    connectWith: ".location-chips",
    start: function(e, ui){
      source = dest = e.target;
      console.log(source.outerText.split("close").filter(function(o){return o}).join(";"))
    },
    change: function(e, ui){
      if(ui.sender){
        dest = e.target
      }
    },
    stop: function(e, ui){

      var dText = dest.outerText.split("close").filter(function(o){return o}).join(";")
      $(dest).siblings("input").val(dText).trigger("change")
      console.log(dText)

      if(source != dest){
        var sText = source.outerText.split("close").filter(function(o){return o}).join(";")
        $(source).siblings("input").val(sText).trigger("change")
        console.log(sText)
      }

    }
```

Note that I'm storing my data in a string with semi-colons as the delimiter.

I'm not sure how stable this is, since I'm using undocumented inner-workings of the chips feature. It's unfortunate that the MaterializeCSS team has shot down requests to make chips sortable as a built-in feature.